# MongoDB with Spring Data - Avoid $and operator

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongotemplate

I want to create the following query using MongoDB api for Spring Data:

```
{ "someField": "someValue", otherField: "otherValue"}
```

The only way I found to do this is:

```
Criteria someFieldCriteria = Criteria.where("someField").is("someValue");
Criteria otherFieldCriteria = Criteria.where("otherField").is("otherValue");
Criteria andCriteria = new Criteria.andOperator(someFieldCriteria, otherFieldCriteria)
```

But this compiles to:

```
{ $and: [{ "someField": "someValue"}, { otherField: "otherValue"}] }
```

Anyone knows? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`and(String key)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/query/Criteria.html#and-java.lang.String-).

Something like

```
Criteria andCriteria = Criteria.where("someField").is("someValue").and("otherField").is("otherValue");
```